# Android remote JDBC connection

Tags: android, jdbc, pervasive

I'm trying to query a Pervasive database on my file server which is on a network with several other computers. On the router, I've set the appropriate ports to forward to the file server which is running the PSQL engine.

[image]

by visitng ip4.me, I got the ip address of the router.

here's the code:

```
class Task implements Runnable {
    public void run() {

        String routerIP ="*.*.*.*"; //blanked it out for privacy reasons

        //String url = "jdbc:pervasive://192.168.1.139:1583/DB";  // THIS WORKS LOCALLY 
        String url = "jdbc:pervasive://" + routerIP + ":1583/DB";  //this throws exception
    String query = "select NAME from CUSTOMER";
    Statement stmt;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.pervasive.jdbc.v2.Driver");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("ClassNotFoundException:", e.toString());
        toast1.show();
    }
    try {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "username", "password");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();

        int i = 1;
        while (rs.next()) {
            for (i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
                Log.d("Data", rs.getString(i));
                myStringArray1.add(rs.getString(i));
            }
        }

        stmt.close();
        conn.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Log.d("Error", ex.toString());
        toast2.show();
    }
}
}
```

A couple of different things are happening.  When I try the connection on the local wifi (same network as the file server), I get `java.sql.SQLException: java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)`

Attempting to use a 4G connection (what I intend to use), I get
`java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /*.*.*.* (port 1583): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)`

(again, I blanked out the ip for privacy reasons)

Comment: What version and edition (workgroup / server) of PSQL are you using?  Can you use the PCC using the IP Address (inside or outside the network)?   DOes the machine where PSQL is running have a firewall and are the ports (3351 / 1583) open on it?

Comment: not sure about the firewall, but I have to assume yes.  I think PCC means Pervasive Control Center, and yes I can access it from any computer on the network.  Note, the connection does work on the same network if I use the ip address distributed from the router (192.168.1.139)

Comment: What version and edition (workgroup / server) of PSQL are you using?

Comment: when I go to help>about in PCC, the version number is 10.30.017.000